# Надо помощь с парсингом елемента(числа) с сайта на пайтоне

Tags: python, парсер

Новичок в парсинге. Только начал разбираться. Суть в том что надо спарсить актуальное число с сайта по статистике ковида для програмы на пайтоне. Пропробовал что-то набросать, но парситься почему-то много текста, хотя задавал названия класов вроде правильно. Как по мне, это изза одинакових названий класов в блоках.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://covid19.gov.ua/'




def parse():
    HEADERS = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
    }
    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'fields')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'title' : item.find('div', class_ = 'field-value').get_text(strip = True)
        })

        for comp in comps:
            print(comp['title'])

parse()
```

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто надо взять другие теги/классы.
Ибо данные там лежат в таких однотипных блоках:

```
<div class="one-field light-box info-count flex-w-50">
    <span class="field-label">хворих на Covid-19</span>
    <div class="field-value">
        3 400 340
    </div>
</div>
```

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://covid19.gov.ua/'

def parse():
    HEADERS = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
    }
    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'info-count')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'title' : item.find('span', class_ = 'field-label').get_text(strip = True),
            'number': int(item.find('div' , class_ = 'field-value').get_text(strip = True).replace(' ', ''))
        })

    print(comps)

parse()
```

```
[{'title': 'хворих на Covid-19', 'number': 3400340}, 
 {'title': 'одужало', 'number': 2877021}, 
 {'title': 'летальних випадків', 'number': 84149}, 
 {'title': 'протестовано', 'number': 15746389}, 
 {'title': 'нових випадків за добу', 'number': 15936}, 
 {'title': 'госпіталізацій за добу', 'number': 3208}, 
 {'title': 'летальних випадків за добу', 'number': 608}]
```